# Vee validate not returning error message back from rule

Tags: vuejs3, vee-validate

Quite new to vee validate with Vue and trying a simple example.

I have a VSCode extension that is making use of a Webview and I am using the VSCode toolkit ui.
In my simple example, I have this in my script setup section

```
function validateField(value: any) {
 console.log("value is" , value);
 if (!value) {
   return 'This field is required';
 }
 if (value.length > 8) {
   return 'This field must not exceed 8 characters';
 }
 return true;
}
```

And in my template

```
<div v-if="item.argName === 'user'">
                     <Field name="field" as="vscode-text-field" v-model="baseArgs[profIndex].mergedArgs.missingArgs[index].value" :rules="validateField" >  
                       {{ setUpper(item.argName) }} 
                     </Field>   
                     <ErrorMessage name="field"/>
```

I am not getting any error message back when I enter an invalid value.

Must be something obvious but I am not seeing it.

validateField is working fine
[image]